# Executing several input cell simultaneously with parallelization

Tags: parallelization

How can I execute more than one input cell simultaneously using different processor. For example consider this two cells

```
Grid[ParallelTable[ContourPlot[Sin[m x] Sin[n y] - Cos[n x] Cos[m y],
{x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},MaxRecursion -> 5], {m, 2}, {n, 2}]]//TimeUsed
T1end=DateString[]
```

and

```
T2begin=DateString[]
Grid[ParallelTable[ContourPlot[Sin[m x] Cos[n y] - Cos[m x] Sin[n y],
{x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},MaxRecursion -> 5], {m, 2}, {n, 2}]]//TimeUsed
```

I hit the shift+enter for the second cell after 3 second of the first one but the execution starts after finishing the first cell and I always get **T2begin=T1end**.

where; **T2begin** = Starting time of second job (given by `DateString[]`) and
**T1end** = Finishing time of first job.

What I want is to use half of the processors for the first job and use the aother half for the second job simultaneously (starting from the moment I hit the shift+enter) which will give **T2begin < T1end**, i.e. the second job will start before the completion of first job.

(I am working with 8 processors.)

Comment: Why do you use `TimeUsed` rather than `AbsoluteTiming`?

Comment: @YvesKlett: `TimeUsed[]` is not anything important here. Only thing I want to assure that the second job starts before the first job ends and you get `T2begin-T1end < 0`.

Comment: Are the jobs different? In your example they could simply be tied into one `ParallelTable`.

Comment: @YvesKlett : sorry for not clarifying that. Yes, they are two different jobs with completely different structure and cant' be executed simultaneously. I have to run them one after another and while doing so the second one always starts after finishing the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way (other than using one `ParallelTable`) to do this with [`ParallelSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelSubmit.html)`:

```
Pause[1]; Pause[1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> (* {2.000000, Null}*)

```
ParallelSubmit[Pause[1]]; ParallelSubmit[Pause[1]];
WaitAll[%] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> (* {1.006000, Null}*)

Comment: thanks @YvesKlett. but I need a little more than that. Each of the jobs have several parallel jobs. So I want to allot 4 processor for the first job and then go for the second job and use another 4 processor to execute them. I have to submit them one after another, executing two different cell and I want them to run together.

Comment: Could `ParallelSubmit` be called "retroactively", i.e. execute one cell first, and then another inside `ParallelSubmit`?

Comment: @shrx I do not quite get your meaning...

Comment: @YvesKlett Like this: `Pause[1]; ParallelSubmit[Pause[1]];` and it should take 1 second to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case it is better to run two copies of the program. The first is to do the calculations for the first problem, the second - on the second. Communication is possible through export and import files. The number of processes for parallel computing have to adjust manually.